# Electrical question could use some advice

Tags: electrical

Hi guys the power went out in the living room and when I turn the oven on it turns the power to the living room back on. I had the electric company come out and they said everything is good on their end, the breaker is good. I have just no clue what is going on. I still need to try and turn off the main break and turn on a few times to see if that works (currently at work)

Comment: You have classic lost neutral symptoms. *Most* of the time (my electrician has told me stories...) it is a utility problem, but sometimes it is in your panel.

Comment: If power company stuff is okay, then a loose connection in the panel is best guess.  Is it only the living room or are other rooms affected?  Oven should be 240/both sides of the panel, so maybe a loose hot, but other stuff should be affected.

Comment: Only the living room is effected ill  have to check the panel .

Comment: The linked Q&A isn't quite right.  In your case you lost a hot wire, not the neutral.   But same other than that, still probably the power company's problem.

Comment: Sorry about that but the kitchen lights and the outlet that a microwave is plugged into is out as well.